# What does T.lazy do in web2py?

Tags: internationalization, web2py

I am studying web2py. I read example open source code. In one application (storpy), the programmer uses `T.lazy` repeatedly inside the models file `db.py` such as this:

```
...
Field('comment', 'text'),
Field('cover', 'upload', autodelete=True))

T.lazy = False
db.dvds.title.requires = [IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=T('Missing data') + '!'), IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'dvds.title', error_message=T('Already in the database') + '!')]
...
T.lazy = True
```

Why does the programmer set `T.lazy` first to `False` then to `True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `T()` is lazy -- when you call it, it doesn't actually do the translation but instead returns a lazyT object, which isn't translated until serialized in a view. If you set `T.lazy=False`, that will force immediate translation, so calling `T('some string')` will return the actual translated string instead of a lazyT object.

Note, starting with the upcoming release, instead of having to toggle `T.lazy` to `False` and `True`, you will be able to do `T('some string', lazy=False)` to force an immediate translation for a single call. Other ways to force immediate translation are `str(T('some string'))` or `T('some string').xml()` -- `str()` serializes the lazyT object (and `.xml()` simply calls `str()`).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. One more question: Why is there a need for immediate translation?

Comment: For example, sometimes date formats like '%Y/%m/%d' are translated but need to be passed to functions internally, such as `date.strftime(T('%Y/%m/%d', lazy=False))`.